# PHP function return not assigned to variable

Tags: php

I have a function that boils down to something like this:

```
function do_something_cool() {
    return array(
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
    );
}
```

Then, later on in the file, these four lines:

```
$var1 = array();
$var1 = do_something_cool();
print_r(do_something_cool());
print_r($var1);
```

The array returned by the function is only printed when I directly print out the return, printing the variable results in an empty array.

I have also tried using array_merge to assign the array, no luck.

I don't even know where to start figuring out what's going on.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: I see differently http://codepad.viper-7.com/XhdX0Y

Comment: Most likely your `$var1 = do_something_cool();` has a typo in your real code.

Comment: probably `$var1` is being overwritten somewhere you didn't notice

Comment: As you can imagine, you made an error. Not just ask about assumptions, troubleshoot and find your problem instead.

Comment: I actually have checked and double-checked for typos, run it in several different environments, rewriting it, and get the same results every time.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the example, as simple as you've posted it, and it will work:

```
function do_something_cool() {
    return array(
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
    );
}

$var1 = array();
$var1 = do_something_cool();
print_r(do_something_cool());
print_r($var1);
```

Output (as expected):

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
)
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
)
```

That's because

```
$var1 = do_something_cool();
```

will just overwrite `$var1` with the return value of `do_something_cool()`. There is no *hidden magic*.

So I guess your problem isn't as simple as the one you've posted and there are other errors in your code.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34e180b5f31bcb71393ca72b44427b3b6de7227b  Here is a sandbox running the code if you want to add it in your answer! (with the output it gives)